# Node request module not returning the right statusCode

Tags: node.js, facebook, express, request

Basically what I'm trying to do is to check whether a pagename or name already exist on facebook or twitter based on the response status code without using an api.

> For example for facebook,
>   "https://www.facebook.com/iwannaseeifavailablenotoken",

I should get a status 404 for facebook since name does not exist yet, the response for twitter is correct. So I was wondering why the response.statusCode for facebook is incorrect?

```
async.parallel({
    twitter: (callback) => {
        let twitter = {
            url    : `https://www.twitter.com/${req.query.name}`,
            method : 'GET'
        }

        request(twitter, (error, response, result) => {
            callback(error, response.statusCode)
        }); 
    },
    facebook: (callback) =>{
        let facebook = {
            url    : `https://www.facebook.com/${req.query.name}`,
            method : 'GET'
        }

        request(facebook, (error, response, result) => {
            callback(error, response.statusCode)
        }); 
    },
}, (err, results) => {
      if(err){
         return res.status(500).json({
             error: true,
             message: err
          })
      }

      res.status(200).json({
        success  : true,
        message  : "Successfully fetched the url.", 
        twitter  : results.twitter == 200 ? `Status: ${results.twitter}: Account exist` : `Status: ${results.twitter}: Does not exist`,
        facebook : results.facebook == 200 ? `Status: ${results.facebook}: Account exist` : `Status: ${results.facebook}: Does not exist`,
      });
  });
```

Comment: Most likely because Facebook does not want you to be able to do this in the first place. You might get a 404 when you test this in your browser; but they probably can easily enough differentiate your server-side request from a “genuine” one made by a real user browser, and then answer it differently.

Comment: I know this is a dumb question but is there a way to bypass this?